# how to combine or concatenate two video files with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, combine, avi

I have tried to concatenate 2 video files (avi) into one sigle video:

```
cat input1.avi input2.avi | ffmpeg -f avi -i - -vcodec copy -acodec copy final.avi
```

.. but this does not concatenate the videos. The duration of the final video is not the sum of the input videos.

How can this be done correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/4414935

Answer (score 6):

Try using mencoder:

```
$ mencoder -ovc lavc start.avi end.avi -o complete.avi
```

I know it isn't using ffmpeg, but it definitely works.

Using `cat` won't likely work with avi files because information is stored in the opening bytes of an avi.  Thus `cat` simply shunts the two binary files together, leaving a broken bit in the middle and incorrect metadata at the start.

Comment: I tried avidemux but Mencoder was just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This: http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/ might help you.  If you want to merge the files, use the ready software, if you want to learn how to do it, use the source.